# Protocol buffers, C# and NetworkStream: messages are never received

Tags: c#, networking, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use ProtocolBuffers over a `NetworkStream` but the messages are never fully received.

Here is my server:

```
var listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 4989);
listener.Start();

while (true)
{
    var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var message = ServerMessage.Parser.ParseFrom(client.GetStream());
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    });
}
```

Here is my client:

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);//Wait for server to start

var client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect("localhost", 4989);

while (true)
{
    var message = new ServerMessage
    {
        Time = (ulong)DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks,
        Type = MessageType.Content
    };
    message.WriteTo(client.GetStream());

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

A full repro solution is available here: https://github.com/IanPNewson/ProtobufNetworkStreamIssue

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

protobuf is not a terminated protocol, by which I mean: there is literally nothing that says when an individual message ends. Because of this, by default: APIs like `ParseFrom` read *until the end of the stream*, and in an open `Socket`/`NetworkStream`: that would only happen if you sent a single message and then closed the outbound connection (not having any more bytes *at the moment* is not sufficient - it would need to see an actual EOF on the stream, which means you could only send one message per socket).

Because of this, you usually use *framing* with protobuf, which means: some means of denoting individual messages in an open stream. This is usually done via a length-prefix (you can't use a sentinel value to terminate, because protobuf can contain any byte value).

Some APIs include convenience methods for this (the `*WithLengthPrefix` APIs in protobuf-net, for example, although you can't just drop that in place here) - or you can implement it yourself manually. Alternatively, perhaps consider something like gRPC which deals with all the framing etc semantics *for you*, so you can concentrate on doing interesting work. I have a variant of gRPC that works on bare sockets, if you really don't want to deal with the full HTTP/2 side of gRPC.

Comment: Thanks Marc! I actually mainly wanted it for the framing, so I'll look at gRPC instead.

Comment: Would you mind adding a link to your gRPC socket variant please?

Comment: @Ian https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.GrpcLite

Comment: The convenience methods you mentioned are called `WriteDelimitedTo` and `ReadDelimitedFrom`. Thanks!